# Correct way to interpret odds ratio

Tags: interpretation, ratio, odds

I'm looking at a table of logistic regression results. Specifically, the table shows "Logistic regression model of hypertension status in relation to lead biomarkers in the normative aging study, Stratified by calcium intake".

The outcome variable is the presence of hypertension (1-yes, 0-no).

The covariates are: age>=70 (1/0), family history of hypertension (1/0), ever smoker (1/0), BMI (kg/m^2), blood lead, tibia bone lead levels, and patella bone levels. 
The results are stratified by calcium intake (Low calcium intake, and High Calcium intake).

My question is really a more simple, basic one: Why is it not the same to say the following two things:

(a) "odds of hypertension are 3 times higher in males aged>=70 WITH a family history of hypertension versus males <70 years without a family history of hypertension, adjusted for the other variables"

(b) "odds of hypertension are 3 times higher in males aged<70 WITHOUT a family history of hypertension versus males aged>=70 WITH a family history of hypertension, adjusted for the other variables"?

Please let me know if I can be clearer, and thanks so much in advance!  A snapshot of the table is below:[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question by editing it so that when you say "higher" we know higher than what? You seem to be trying to interpret an interaction so more details of that would also help.

Comment: Hi Mdewey, Thanks so much -- my original question text is edited and I added a snapshot. Do you have thoughts on the question?

Comment: I do not see sex as a predictor in the tables. Which model are you trying to interpret?

Comment: Right -- thanks! The study was done only on men, n=471 men

Comment: Both of your statements seem to be about interactions between age and family histiry but I do not see that included in any of the models.

Comment: @mdewey I agree the language is highly suggestive of interaction, but it is in fact not. She seems to be interpreting the joint effect of old age and of family history as an additive contrast.

Comment: Hi mdewey and Adam0, that's right -  I'm not looking at interactions, I'm only looking at the additive joint effects of age/family history. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are discussing appears to be establishing the baseline for which your coefficients are deviating from.  There are four models in the output you provided (each stratified); let's assume we are dealing with model A with low calcium intake for this exercise

From the table you provided, it appears that No History (of family hypertension) and <70 years old represent the baselines.

**Statement A** suggests the following relationship concerning odds ratios.  Notice the coefficients in the table you provided support this interpretation ($1.29*2.34 = 3.0$)

[image: statement A]

**Statement B** suggests that hypertension is higher among men who are <70 with No History (of family hypertension).

[image: statement B]

Statement B doesn't seem right and would be hard to support from the table you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The explanations would be equivalent if you replaced HIGHER with LOWER in either case. I'm assuming the odds are generally higher among older men with a family history, making statement a) the correct(er) one. The exposures in the comparison and referent group are inverted in either statement.

Comment: Am I right that the only reason you say "I'm assuming" is that there is some chance an interaction, if examined, would show a different result?

Comment: @rolando2 no, my assumption is that older age and family history are in fact associated with a greater probability of the outcome as intuition would suggest. Your comment loops back to a different, larger problem of model correctness: No such statement along the lines of OP's comment could be made if effect modification were present since the actual odds ratio would vary across strata of the effect modifier.

Comment: Thank you;  can you say why the need for assumption or intuition when the table shows all 8 relevant odds ratio estimates to be >1?  Is it that some of the confidence intervals are wide?

Comment: @rolando2 Imgur is a blocked domain from where I am posting. It wasn't necessary to view the graphic to answer the OP's question, but I did have to state what might have been a possible misunderstanding. You're right, there's no need for me to assume anything if the ORs are > 1 as you say.